# Using javascript to take HTML form inputs

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I would like to use javacript to simply look at a specific HTML form (i.e. radio button), find the user's selection and then respond in various ways.

Is there a way javascript can read user input or selected responses for a form?

Comment: http://jquerytutorialwithexamples.com/2014/10/get-checked-selected-radio-button-value-in-jquery/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes there are lots of ways to do this.**

You can check user input when changed. One of them is below.

```
 <input type="text" onchange="changed(this);"/>
```

This input will call `changed()` function with the paremetre of self. So you can control its value and do some things.

```
function changed(input){
  alert(input.value)  // check for input value
  if(input.value.length > 54){ //do if value is longer than 54 characters
     //Do something
  }
}
```

---

You can find lots of ways on the internet. You can try using jQuery which will be easier for you.

```
$("#myInput").change(function(){   //select the input box which id is 'myInput' then run function when its value changed each time
    alert("Wow, my value changed to:"+$(this).val())   //Get value with $(this).val() and alert!
});
```

You can also bind this to all input fields using `$("input").change(function(){`

---

Changing my answer by your request.

```
<form name="myForm">
   <!--Lots of divs here with input. You must hide these divs without touching form! -->
</form>
```

When you are on the last page all you need to do is

```
function listUserValues(){
   var els=document.myForm.elements;
   var l=els.length;
   for (var i=0; i<l; i++)
   {
      alert('Field Name: '+els[i].name+'\nField Type: '+els[i].type+'\nField Value: '+els[i].value);
      //Do whatever you want with each value here.
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! So what I am trying to do is store the values when the user hits "next page" and reveal the next hidden div. So I don't want to store it as soon as it changes, only when they hit this button. Also, I don't want values on different "pages." to overlap.

Is there another function rather than "onchange"? I guess I can store the values in temporary variables until they hit next page...

Comment: When user clicked next page, top link being changed?

Comment: No, just the current div becomes hidden and the next one shows.

Comment: Thank you! This looks like it should do the trick. However the returned alert doesn't seem to record the user's value. For instance if a user checks one radio button or check box, the alert says Value: on for each choice